Distinct sums and products of adjacent numbers
Given a sequence of N integers you also write the sum and product of each pair of adjacent numbers, giving you a total of 3N-2 numbers. Can you arrange the 7 integers from 2 to 8, such that the above procedure gives you all distinct 3N-2 numbers?

I think this is

 Impossible

Reasoning

 Consider just the sums of adjacent pairs.
 The total sum of these sums would be at least 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 = 69.
 This must be equal to twice the sum of the original numbers minus the numbers at each end which is, at most, 2(2+3+4+5+6+7+8)-2-3 = 70 - 5 = 65.
 65 < 69, hence it is impossible to satisfy the conditions.


Sorry I don't understand you

@DmitryKamenetsky Which line is confusing?

This argument seems right to me, and is quite elegant. Add the 15 in your total sum and you can skip the need to concern yourself with the minimum endpoints.

@kagami Seven integers produce six adjacent pairs so six sums.

o, right. Whoops!

Just for clarity, I would add something like: "If it was possible, the total sum is at least.... =69 .  But in same time, this will be equal also to at most..... = 65 which is less than 69. "

@franckvivien I will try to highlight for clarity, thanks

What do you mean total sums of these sums? Where does 9+10+...+14 come from?

@DmitryKamenetsky Those are the smallest values the six sums of adjacent pairs can take (e.g. the six numbers after 2,...,8).  Thus they result in the smallest possible sum.  It is a very elegant argument (+1).

@DmitryKamenetsky : products do not even seem to matter ... is there perhaps some misunderstanding or flaw in the question formulation ?

Ah I get it. You started with 9 because we can't use 8 (of course). Great solution. Products don't even matter - I missed this as I was using a computer to design the puzzle.

I don't get the conclusion that total sum of these sums would be at least 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 = 69. Surely if you take the sequence 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 then the sums are 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 = 60

@Ivo since we want distinct numbers, no sum can be 5 nor 7: these numbers are already there in the list. Thus we have to arrange the first numbers such that their pairwise sums are at least 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13 ,14.

Ah of course. Thanks for explaining

I think the bit that keeps variously people (including me) confused for a while is that we want the N original numbers and the N-1 sums (and the products) all distinct from one another. Hence the sums need to start at least at 9 because 2 to 8 are the set of original numbers.


 For that to be possible, the $6$ sums must range from $9$ to $15$. The sum of $2$ and the number(s) next to it must give $9$ or $10$. In turn, at least $5$ products must be $16$ or more.  If $2$ is somewhere in the middle, it's like so:  $...827...$  $16$ and $14$ are products, so they can't be sums. So anything save $14$ from $9$ to $15$ are the sums, but the latter can only be obtained through $7+8=15$.  So $2$ is at one of the ends, and the number next to it is $7$ or $8$. If it's $7$, $14$ will be a product, so anything save $14$ from $9$ to $15$ are the sums, and $15=8+7$, meaning $8$ follows $7$. Then $13$ can only be obtained through $8+5$, so $5$ follows, but then $12$ is unreachable.  If $8$ follows $2$, only $7$ or $6$ can come next to the former because either $15$ or $14$ is used as a sum. Then $13=7+6$. The arrangement is like so:  $2, 8, (7,6), (6,7),...$.  $12=7+5$, but $11$ is unobtainable.

